# Unable to forward port to computer within my Mikrotik LAN

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, firewall, port-forwarding

I do not have extensive background in networking and I want to achieve something simple within my LAN. I have a server running on port 8080 on my computer and I want to make it accessible through the router's public IP. I have done that with regular residential gateways many times, but recently I switched to Mikrotik hAP ac² and cannot seem to succeed. I tried adding the following rule:

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-port=8080 action=dst-nat protocol=tcp to-address=192.168.*.* to-port=8080
```

but when I type `<public-ip>:8080` in the browser it gets stuck for some time and then returns *This site can't be reached*. I tried to configure it through WebFig, but without success. The only other rule I have is a pre-existing `masquerade`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Test it from outside your LAN. If the router can't perform [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) it won't work from inside.

Comment: That was the issue indeed. As a networking newbie, I had no idea such thing existed. Thank you very much. You can post it as an answer, since it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to access an internal machine from inside the same LAN by entering its external WAN IP address, the router must be capable of performing [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning), which is not a common attribute in domestic routers.

Otherwise, you can only test access from outside the LAN - hook up to a mobile tether or cafe wifi etc.